# Getting error while installing Android SDK in windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: android, java

Hi I am trying to install android latest SDK in my windows 7 home basic 64 bit. I installed Java su 7 in my system before that. I checked java installation with java -version in cmd and the Path as well and  it's giving correct . But when i try to install SDK, it says it can't find Java path.

- Steps i followed while installing Java JDk.......
- Downloaded JDKfrom oracle site.........
- Installed it in my system..............
- It's taking path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\bin....like this
- I went to advanced system settings and environmental variables then system variables    selected path variable clicked on edit option and added path in the end.

Again clicked on new system variable JAVA_HOME added jdk path..........

Is there any wrong in installation steps i followed.

Comment: is `javac` command running properly ?

Comment: @Lucifer javac command is working properly.......

Comment: i think you should go for Java 6

Comment: @subodh I set totally two variables one is in user variables i created a new variable called path and added my jdk path. Same like that i added path end of the path variable in environmental variables. I didn't set specifically JAVA_HOME variable.........

Comment: type this on your cmd prompt:  echo %JAVA_HOME%

Comment: the path i am getting when i gave echo %JAVA_HOME% in cmd is c:\programfiles\java\jdk1.6.0_35\bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JDK-6` instead of `JDK-7` and then add jdk path to the system `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME`. in environment variables.

like this `Computer-->Properties-->Advanced System settings-->advanced tab-->system variables-->add PATH in user variables and JAVA_HOME in System variables.`

Comment: i am not sure, but i faced problem with jdk-7 , shifted to jdk-6 working fine now..

Comment: I created that variable also but not installing............wait i will try with jdk-6.......